# Empty Recycler view is not getting updated with new data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I intialize my recycler view adapter with an empty arraylist initially.
Then later once I fetch data from API I try to update the adapter by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` but none of call back methods in my adapter is getting fired

```
void initRecyclerView() 
    {     
            myList = new ArrayList<>();
            myRecyclerAdapter = new myRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), myList, "");
            myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerAdapter);
            linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    }
```

After getting data from API I just update the adapter as follow :

```
void updateRecyclerView(ArrayList<Data> newList)
   {
        if (myList.isEmpty())
                    linearLayoutManager.removeAllViews();
                myList.clear();
                myList.addAll(newList);             
                myRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

Comment: Did you check if `updateRecyclerView` did get called? Why do you remove all views in `linearLayoutManager` while you only want to update your recyclerview? Also, it's better to use brackets, even when the `if` only has 1 statement.

Comment: `updateRecyclerView` is getting called with new set of records in newList. I've removed `removeAllViews' of `linearLayoutManager`. Still it's not working.

Comment: Can you post your Adapter code as well?

Comment: Is `updateRecyclerView` running on UI thread?

Comment: Yes it's in my fragment's handler.I'll call this inside runOnUIThread explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a costliest mistake and ponder around something else instead of looking it at different aspect.

I had `SwipeRefreshLayout` that wraps `RecyclerView`.

I should've just use `setRefreshing(false)` once data downloaded through API call. Instead I used `setVisibility(VIEW.GONE) on my`mSwipeRefreshLayout`.

This visibility change of `SwipeRefreshLayout` impacted `RecyclerView` within.

I hope none will do this mistake. Perhaps someone might come across this tiniest mistake so I Mark my answer as accepted answer.

Comment: I made the same mistake, thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
void updateRecyclerView(ArrayList<Data> newList)
   {
//you don't have to removeviews
      //  if (myList.isEmpty())
                 //    linearLayoutManager.removeAllViews();
                myList.clear();
                myList.addAll(newList);             
                 myRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

Comment: Still it's not populating! After calling notifyDataSetChanged() No effect in adapter.I kept log in every call back method! More over I tried to feed sample data into adapter which works perfectly alright! FYI : newList has items init! It's not empty!

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to set layout manager and then set adapter to list :

```
void initRecyclerView() 
{     
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myRecyclerAdapter = new myRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), myList, "");
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

Also pay attention that if you want to change data set or notify your adapter about the changes, you should do it in your main thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
     myList.clear();
     myList.addAll(newList);             
     myRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
});
```